# Soundcloud created_at[from] and created_at[to] not returning expected results

Tags: javascript, api, search, soundcloud

I am trying to single out a certain track on Soundcloud by setting the created_at[from] and created_at[to] filter as referenced on [Soundcloud's API Docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) a day before and after the track was created in combination with a genre tag to ensure only the expected track is returned.

```
SC.get('/tracks', {
        // q: 'Diplo&Friends',
        genres: 'Diplo&Friends', 
        //title: 'Boombox Cartel Diplo & Friends Mix', 
        created_at: {
            from: '2016-01-26 00:00:01',
            to: '2016-01-28 00:00:01'
        }
        //ids: '243959257'
    }).then(function(tracks) {
      console.log(tracks);
    });
```

This results in five total objects, four of which are tracks with the correct ("diplo&friends") genre however created outside of the search query by substantial time(up to a year).

So far the only time I have been able to single out the track is with the id, however I am building an application that will only be taking in genre and dates (for the time being, I may end up adding extra filters) so this will not suffice.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499287/query-soundcloud-api-using-created-at-filter) that the filters' priority is unknown, and tried the suggested solution with unfortunately even less accuracy.

I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421002/dates-in-soundcloud-api) that "[searching with date queries] does not currently work, as with many of the other queries on SoundCloud." However that was almost three years ago, can anyone verify if that's still the case?

Thank you!